# Help with first Core Data project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

This is my first project which I've encountered that I can't get by on `NSUserDefaults` peppered with some `NSCoding` protocol. I've been asked to write some POS software.

Essentially, the App needs to store a bunch of products, prices and sales accounts. The user should be able to add items and accounts, and track the balance of accounts over time. The balance of an account should be able to be carried over from one "Session" (time period) to the next.

I'm comfortable with the concepts, but I'd like to be confident that I'm modeling this right. **Here's how I've modeled my data. I'd like to know if I've done this properly or if there are any glaring errors/omissions.**

I've created an "Account" Entity, which has the following properties:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Account ID
- Group
- There is a relationship to the transaction entity.

I've created an entity for each Session. Again, a session is just like a fiscal month. The session will have a custom name and an ID.

- Session ID
- Session Name
- There is a relationship to all of the accounts that are applied to that session.

There are of course, products, which have a name and ID. There is also a relationship to the "price" object, so I can change the prices without affecting balances.

Please see this screenshot from Xcode 4 which explains my model in its entirety:

[image]

**Edit:**

Looking at this, it seems that I'm missing some important info, such as dates of transactions etc. That said, **am I on the right track?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need to have an entity for price, as it will likely just be a float. I'd recommend adding a price attribute to your product entity instead.

I don't know if transactions will need names or not, I suppose if you want to have notes then they should.

Also transactions should probably have a to-many relationship with products.

Will this be used on a single device or will there be many users? If each user (account) is responsible for its own data then it may make more sense to have transactions/session rather than transactions/user.

Comment: Are floats really sufficient for dealing with money?

Comment: Also, the issue with the relationships being of the wrong type is likely a flaw in my understanding of Core Date. Please feel free to elaborate. I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Also, for now this is for a single device, managing all the accounts. I haven't begun to have those nightmares yet, about syncing Core Data.

Comment: @Josh should I use Core Data's decimal type then?

Comment: @Moshe: I don't really have any experience with Core Data, but yes, a decimal type _should_ be appropriate for money. The issue is how it stores fractional values -- floats are imprecise in this respect, and will cause lost accuracy.

Comment: I don't think I am getting more accurate than pennies, but it's still a valid concern. Also, it's just addition an subtraction. No multiplication or division.

Answer (score 3):

It has been my experience that point of sale transactions list all the data that is necessary to recreate the receipt in three tables, a header (think date of sale, singular tracking entity), a set of records for all items being sold (linking back to the sale header), and a set of records for all the methods of payment (again linked back to the sale header).

This will give you the opportunity to rebuild the individual transactions in the future. Also, this is a simplistic model, but should suffice for what you're asking. Nominally yo uwould also keep track of applied discounts on a per-line-item basis, and per-invoice discounts, and per-group discounts, and etc.

What's the relationship between sessions and transactions?

Comment: A session is essentially a time period. An account is where "everything happens". Credit is applied at the beginning of a session and then purchases/deposits/withdrawals can be made. Accounts are open or closed for a given session, but that is not enforced in code. A transaction simple effects the balance over a  session. At the end of a session, the balance can be refunded, or rolled over. So, there is no direct relationship, but there's an implied relationship.

Comment: If a transaction effects the balance over a session, then is there a relation between them?

Comment: Well, no. There is a relationship between the balance and the transaction, but not the session itself.

Comment: Consider your words again. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: I suppose you're saying that there really is a relationship, as in the timeframe when a transaction occurred. I just want to reiterate that I don't refer to a conventional session as we refer to it in computing. I mean a camp session (a month), not a "log in/log out" session.